# Mailed 2018 taxes-Not processed so no AGI or pin...how do I efile?

Tags: united-states, adjusted-gross-income

I mailed my 2018 Federal Taxes 4/11/20...they have not been processed yet.  I was told by IRS to go ahead and file my 2019 taxes...I want to use efile, since mailing didn't work well.  There isn't any record of my 2018 AGI and I don't have a pin from last year.

Comment: You would only have a PIN if you e-filed. So if you mailed your previous tax returns, then you would not have a PIN.

Answer (score 1):

If you did not file a tax return for 2018, you can still file in 2019 by [selecting 0 as your prior year AGI](https://support.taxslayer.com/hc/en-us/articles/360015710352-I-didn-t-file-a-return-last-year-What-information-do-I-enter-to-sign-my-return-).  This of course will only work if the 2018 taxes haven't been processed yet, but the good news is you get fairly quick feedback of that information.

You could also [request a transcript](https://www.irs.gov/individuals/get-transcript) of your 2018 taxes, in the case that they have accepted and processed the 2018 return and you just don't know it yet.  6 months is a very long time for them to not have processed it yet, so I'd be concerned, and consider re-sending the 2018 taxes in as well.